# npm install zmq fails

Tags: node.js, npm, package, zeromq

I tried `npm install zmq` and I got:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/lucas/dir/node_modules/zmq/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o
../binding.cc:28:17: fatal error: zmq.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
zmq.target.mk:94: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/lucas/dir/node_modules/zmq/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/lucas/dir/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v7.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN projectName@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "zmq"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! zmq@2.15.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.15.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the zmq package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs zmq
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls zmq
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/lucas/dir/npm-debug.log
```

Here's the pastebin of that `npm-debug.log`:

http://pastebin.com/UGLDEWin

Does anybody have any idea of what's happening? Seems like error in the compilation or so. As you see, my nodejs is version 7.x, not an old one. And NPM is 4.x, should work, right?

Comment: updated npm to 4.1.2 and it still won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

then, relaunch npm install.

If it fails again, you can try to install node-gyp globally:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is on the zmq@2.15.3 install script.
Have you try to:

    `sudo apt-get install libtool pkg-config build-essential autoconf automake`
    `sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev`

Then retry to install the package.

Comment: I changed node version to v9.11.2 then it worked https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/763

Comment: Installing sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev seem to have worked!

Answer (score 3):

Update on latest Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool pkg-config build-essential autoconf automake
sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev
```

Comment: what is "latest ubuntu"?

Comment: @StealthRabbi it was the latest version at the time I wrote it, not sure right now.

Answer (score 1):

**installing on Unix/Mac:**

First install pkg-config and the [ZeroMQ library](http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software).

This module is compatible with ZeroMQ versions 2, 3 and 4. The installation process varies by platform, but headers are mandatory. Most Linux distributions provide these headers with -devel packages like zeromq-devel or zeromq3-devel. Homebrew for OS X provides versions 4 and 3 with packages zeromq and zeromq3, respectively. A Chris Lea PPA is available for Debian-like users who want a version newer than currently provided by their distribution

**For windows**

First install Visual Studio and either Node.js or io.js.

Ensure you're building zmq from a conservative location on disk, one without unusual characters or spaces, for example somewhere like: C:\sources\myproject.

Installing the ZeroMQ library is optional and not required on Windows. We recommend running npm install and node executable commands from a github for windows shell or similar environment.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/zmq

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to avoid the `` Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 `` error after running `sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev` along with making sure I had installed all of the packages from the other answers:

From the docs:

> To use your system's libzmq (if it has been installed and development headers are available):
>
> ```
> npm install zeromq@5 --zmq-external
> ```