# Javascript installation error on Windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, ijavascript

my name's Nilson and I got a problem when I was trying to install javascript in an anaconda environment, windows 10. Here is the image of the error:

[image]

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like VS build tool issue. Do you have the version that is mentioned in red in you image?

Comment: Found the same issue on github: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56577873/15548661, did you test this yet?